# Acrobat Pro: "Optimize Scanned Documents" Batch No Prompts

Tags: pdf-generation, acrobat

How can I use Acrobat XI Pro's (or any other software) to batch optimize thousands of PDF files without prompting per file as Acrobat XI Pro's batch mode seems to do now (with its "Add Document Description" followed by "Optimize Scanned PDF" followed by "Save As"). These documents were erroneously scanned in 600DPI with full color but should have been B&W at 300DPI.

Comment: Sorry, I figured this one out myself. You need to create a new task and manually set things. I used Reduce File Size and Optimize.